# Log in/out button no longer maintaining state

Tags: iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-login

My code was working fine until the past 24 hours. I did not change anything, but now the #fb-button is smaller and it no longer says "Log Out" when it should.

You can see this in action at [Homewrd](http://homewrd.com/pet/4fb8a6bf03fc592e5700046f).

The following code is nested in BODY > ROOT:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId:'271193286279763',
            channelUrl:'//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel',
            status:true,
            cookie:true,
            xfbml:true
        });

        // Conditional UI for landing page
        if (landing) {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {                                                                                                                              
                if(response && response.status == 'connected') {                                                                                                                
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        var heading = $('#goods h1').text().replace('Homewrd','Welcome '+response.first_name+'!');
                        $('#goods h1').text(heading);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
            fbEventful = true;
            if (response.authResponse) {
                fbToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                $('#fb-button').css({'display':'inline','float':'left'});
                $('#toolbox').css({'display':'inline'});
                $('#local-login').hide();
                $('#local-logout').hide();
                currentUser = {
                    fbid:response.authResponse.userID
                }
                displayPicture();
            } else {
                $.cookie('cuat', null);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/logout.json',
                    type:'delete',
                    success:function() {
                        ajaxOff();
                        renderLocal();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',
            function(response) {
                FB.api('/me', function(me){
                  if (me.name) {
                    currentUser = {
                        fbid:me.id,
                        email:me.email,
                        first_name:me.first_name,
                        last_name:me.last_name
                    }
                    params = {
                        fbid: currentUser.fbid,
                        user: {
                            fbid:currentUser.fbid,
                            email:currentUser.email,
                            first_name:currentUser.first_name,
                            last_name:currentUser.last_name
                        }
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url:domain+'/user.json',
                        data:params,
                        dataType:'json',
                        type:'post',
                        success:function(e) {
                            cuat = e.user.auth_token;
                            $.cookie('cuat', cuat, {
                                path:'/',
                                expires:7
                                }
                            );
                            if (rurl) {
                                refreshSession();
                            }
                            if (storedProcedure!==null) {
                                storedProcedure();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                  }
                });
            }
        );

        $('#local-logout a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var x = confirm('Are you sure that you want to logout?');
            if (x===true) {
                ajaxOn();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/logout.json',
                    type:'delete',
                    success:function() {
                        ajaxOff();
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!fbEventful) {
                renderLocal();
            }
        },1000);
    }
</script>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1>Logo Link</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="session">
        <div id="fb-button" autologoutlink="true" class="fb-login-button" scope="publish_stream,email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown,offline_access"></div>
        <div id="fb-picture"></div>
        <div id="local-login"><p>local login link</p></div>
        <div id="local-logout"><p>local logout link</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am having same issue with js-sdk html5 login button, the autologout link is no longer displaying.  This may be by design, since they where hiding alot of private functions from the sdk that used to be in the sdk.

my logout page for example https://anotherfeed.com/login.php  when logged in, used to display logout, in addition buttons with dynamic or static text no longer display text.
<div id="fb-button" class="fb-login-button" >reAuth</div>

Comment: i say by design, because when i click the login button when i am logged in, Facebook is handling the error by telling me i am already logged in, click to close..

Comment: In my case, an authenticated user is not recognized if they are already logged in. This probably has something to do with the way I am combining the callbacks with server-side sessions, so it will take me some time to identify and fix.

Comment: i reduced my login.php page to pure js-sdk to solve the issues that arose from the login for php-sdk.  In my head though i am graph the session from browser. 

just to avoid failures with js-sdk.

 try { $user = $facebook->getUser(); } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {  }
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token'];